# Guidance as to when querying the database for read operation should be done using mass transit request/response for timebound operation

Tags: message-queue, masstransit

For Create operations it is clear that putting the message in the queue is a good idea in case the processing or creation of that entity takes longer than expected and other the other benefits queues bring.

However, for read operations that are timebound (must return to the UI in less than 3 seconds) it is not entirely clear if a queue is a good idea.

http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/request-response.html provides a nice abstraction but it goes through the queue.

Can someone provide some suggestions as to why or why not I would use mass transit or that effect any technology like nservicebus etc for database read operation that are UI timebound? 
Should I only use mass transit only for long running processes?

Comment: full sample code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request/Reply is a perfectly valid pattern for timebound operations. Transport costs in case of, for example, RabbitMQ, are very low. I measured performance of request/response using ServiceStack (which is very fast) and MassTransit. There is an initial delay with MassTransit to cache the endpoints, but apart from that the speed is pretty much the same.

Benefits here are:

- Retries
- Fine tuning of timeouts
- Easy scaling with competing consumers

just to name the most obvious ones.

And with error handling you get your requests ending up in the error queue so there is no data loss and you can always look there to find out what and why went wrong.

*Update*: There is a SOA pattern that describes this (or rather similar) approach. It is called [Decoupled Invocation](http://arnon.me/soa-patterns/decoupled-invocation/).

Comment: Thank you for confirming my thoughts! Sometimes just getting someone that has done it give you reassurance is all that is needed.

Comment: Awesome decoupled invocation! Formal and a nice diagram to convince my fellow engineers!